# PHP how to specify "back one directory level" in an url

Tags: php, mysql, url

I have moved all of my files from being in the root (no folders, not very organised) so that they now reside within the following directory structure in my root folder:

```
css
images
js
scripts
index.html
```

... and this is fine. 
However, I have two or three php scripts which upload files (images) into the images folder above.
This worked fine until I moved all of my files around and now I have been experimenting with things like "../" etc in order to link from the scripts directory, back one level, and then into the images directory.

Any help appreciated guys....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using what you stated above will work, so if you're in css and want to go to images (as an example) you would do the following:

```
require_once('../images/yourimg.png');
```

Comment: That was just an example, to show how to use "../". If you were in /scripts/ and wanted to upload an images to /images/ you would use... `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['your_file']['tmp_name'], '../images/new_name.jpg')`

Answer (score 1):

The require_once is simular to the require() statement but it checks wheter the file has been included already, and if it did, then it won't be included again.

Now for your question, if you have something like:

```
yoursiteurl/scripts/myscript.php
```

And you want that script to write a file to

```
yoursiteurl/images/sampleimage.jpg
```

Then you should reference the image destination to something like this:

`copy('source/file/location/sampleimage.jpg', '../images/sampleimage.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

- As other answer notes, from current directory up a level and then back down to images can be done via a path like `"../images/yourimg.png"`.
- An alternative to that method is using an [HTML `<base>` Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) pointed at the parent directory, after which you would use paths like`"images/yourimg.png"` to reference in images, or `"js/some.js"` in js, etc.